# IL constrained call

Tags: c#, cil, boxing

For this code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new MyStruct().ToString());
    }

    struct MyStruct { }
}
```

the C# compiler generates `constrained callvirt` IL code.

[This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.constrained.aspx) article says:

> For example, if a value type V overrides the Object.ToString() method, a call  V.ToString() instruction is emitted; if it does not, a box instruction and a callvirt  Object.ToString() instruction are emitted. A versioning problem can arise <...> if an override is later added.

So, my question is: why would it be a problem in this case if the compiler will generate a `box` code, not a constrained call?

Comment: doesn't the link you provided already explains it, just before your quote: "Using the constrained prefix also avoids potential versioning problems with value types. If the constrained prefix is not used, different IL must be emitted depending on whether or not a value type overrides a method of System.Object."

Comment: @Selman22, that is why I ask. I don't see why it can't be just box callvirt for both cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `box` instruction creates a copy of the instance in question. Instance methods of value types are permitted to modify the instance they're called on, and if they do, silently calling the method on a copy is the wrong thing to do.

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var myStruct = new MyStruct();
        Console.WriteLine(myStruct.i); // prints 0
        Console.WriteLine(myStruct.ToString()); // modifies myStruct, not a copy of myStruct
        Console.WriteLine(myStruct.i); // prints 1
    }

    struct MyStruct {
        public int i;
        public override string ToString() {
            i = 1;
            return base.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```