# Avoiding Boxing/Unboxing in Method Calls

Tags: c#

I was trying to understand the impact of boxing/unboxing during method calls from Essential C# 6.0 (MarkMichaelis and EricLippert) and ended up being more confused than I began with.

Here is the code from the book:

```
struct A
{
    public int Val {get; set;};
    //doesn't override ToString
}

A vo = new A();;
object thing;
// Boxing
thing = vo;
string text = ((A)thing).ToString();
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

The author goes on to say the following:

> If the receiver is unboxed and the struct does not override
>   ToString(), the base class implementation must be called, and it
>   expects a reference to an object as its receiver. Therefore, the
>   receiver is boxed.

This is the case in the code above where the cast operator to A will unbox 'thing' and then try to call ToString on the temporary. Since ToString() method has not been overridden in struct A, the call to ToString should happen only after the temporary generated by the cast (A) is boxed again or if the compiler optimizes away the unboxing/boxing completely.

But the generated CIL as shown below, does indeed show that 'thing' has been unboxed but the call to ToString() happens without it being boxed again. Please help me understand this.

```
.locals init (valuetype Chapter7.A V_0,
           object V_1,
           string V_2,
           valuetype Chapter7.A V_3)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldloca.s   V_0
  IL_0003:  initobj    Chapter7.A
  IL_0009:  ldloc.0
  **IL_000a:  box        Chapter7.A** //thing = vo
  IL_000f:  stloc.1
  IL_0010:  ldloc.1
  **IL_0011:  unbox.any  Chapter7.A** //((A)thing)
  IL_0016:  stloc.3
  IL_0017:  ldloca.s   V_3 //the temporary where unboxed value is stored
  IL_0019:  constrained. Chapter7.A
  IL_001f:  callvirt   instance string [mscorlib]System.Object::ToString()
```

Comment: It seems to me that your question is best directed at the author. Granted, at least one of them frequents Stack Overflow, but there are more direct means. It may even be an oversight or misstatement in the book. The IL you show is, I presume, generated by the C# 6 compiler. It's clearly generating the reference for the call via the `ldloca` instruction instead of creating a new object, which seems like reasonable behavior to me. The `ToString()` method doesn't care where the reference came from; just that it exists.

Comment: Good question, and related to [IL constrained call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28395401/). It is seen that a CIL `constrained.` (to your `A`) prefix is used. If instead of `.ToString()` you call the non-virtual `.GetType()`, boxing occurs explicitly. With `.ToString()`, it looks like the compiler emits the same CIL no matter if `A` overrides the virtual method or not. Tested with the Roslyn-based C# compiler of Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: This example proves that when `A` does override `ToString`, then surely boxing does not occur: `struct A
  {
    public int I;

    public override string ToString()
    {
      ++I;
      return "";
    }
  }

  static class Program
  {
    static void Main()
    {
      A a;
      a.I = 10;

      a.ToString();

      Console.WriteLine(a.I);
} }` (Evil, do not write structs that mutate when you call an overridden method on them.)

Answer (score 2):

Another way to look at this:

```cs
struct Animal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public Animal(string name, int age)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
    }

    // 'override' means that the method is virtual
    // but struct types are always sealed, there is no need to look for derived types.
    // Implementation is already found, therefore there's no need to look at base class
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Name: {Name}, age: {Age}";
    }
}
```

But let's say that we are not overriding the method `ToString`, then compiler will look at base implementation of the method and will find it, but to use the method it will box the struct to `System.Object` and then call virtual method `ToString`. After that compiler will find the overriden method in the derived abstract class `System.ValueType` and use it.

The relationship looks like this:
`System.Object` -> `System.ValueType` -> `CustomStructType`.

```cs
struct Animal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public Animal(string name, int age)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
    }

    // no overriden method 'ToString' -> compiler need to look at the base class
}
```

```cs
var animal = new Animal("Jeff", 3);
var str1 = animal.ToString();

// you may think about it like this
object o = animal; // boxing here
var str2 = o.ToString(); // uses System.ValueType.ToString
```

That's why it's a good idea to override `ToString` method for struct types.